# Android 4: can't dismiss notification by swiping

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have some code that creates some notifications, it's really basic.

```
int icon = R.drawable.notification;
CharSequence tickerText = "Text";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Text";
CharSequence contentText = "Text";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RequestActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
```

It all works fine in 2.1. 
In 4.0, it all works fine except the swipe-to-dismiss action doesn't work. The notification goes slightly to the side then sticks and bounces back.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: try to remove FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Comment: mh... try to assign the first flag to ntofication.flags and not to bitwise or the first flag. Change notification.flags |= DEFAULT_SOUND to notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; Maybe this will help

Comment: This seems to be some really strange problem. Sorry, I think I cant help you to solve it :(

Answer (score 14):

You can't swipe away your notification, because it is in an "ONGOING"-State.

**First the solution:**

Replace setting flags with following code:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Defaults are for the defaults-section, flags for the flags-section.

**And now the reason why it was ongoing?**

As you might already know flags (and defaults) for notifications are set by a [bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Means each flag has a constant value which is a power of 2. Adding them results in an unique number for a set of flags which makes it real fast to calculate which flags are actually set.

[Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_VIBRATE) and [Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)
have the same contant value of **2**.

Comment: Started shwoing with setOngoing(false) and notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL.

Answer (score 7):

You should use **[setOngoing (boolean ongoing)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean))**

> Set whether this is an "ongoing" notification. Ongoing notifications
>   cannot be dismissed by the user, so your application or service must
>   take care of canceling them. They are typically used to indicate a
>   background task that the user is actively engaged with (e.g., playing
>   music) or is pending in some way and therefore occupying the device
>   (e.g., a file download, sync operation, active network connection).

You can use

```
.setOngoing(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert this line when you make the notification...

```
// Will show lights and make the notification disappear when the presses it
notification.flags == Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```