# Can't dismiss notification by swiping

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a Service that send notification to user acording to some conditions

```
 private void sendNotif(String title, String msg) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

And now I have problems with dismissing this notification.

I try to use:  .setOngoing(true);,

I try to use: notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

Try to use NotificationManager, but dont find way how to startForeground using notification with NotificationManager.

I know that notification is alive while startForeground, so I try to add stopForeground to onDestroy(), but It still didn't help. I google tens of pages, but still can't find way to solve this problem. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to stop the service to hide it or start your service without notification and then show it separately

Comment: i tried this it is working for me .once [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718388/android-4-cant-dismiss-notification-by-swiping)

Comment: what do you mean once?

Comment: you can't hide notification while your foreground service is running. It is google's rule for the users to see that the application is able to run in background.

Comment: @Shekhar, thank you. Already have tried, but I won't help(