# Notification is not swipable to dismiss

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating a Notification in my android app but I want that the notification is cleared from the Notification Bar when user swipe it left or right like all other simple notifications.
I have tried my thing but it is not working. 
This is my Notification Code

```
private void showNotificationPause() {
// Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar_old);
        RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar_expanded);
// showing default album image
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_icon, View.GONE);
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_album_art, View.VISIBLE);
        bigViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.status_bar_album_art,
                Constants.getDefaultAlbumArt(this));

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MusicActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
//        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
//                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                nextIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pcloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                closeIntent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.play);
        bigViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.play);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, song_name.get(pos));
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, song_name.get(pos));

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, singer.get(pos));
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, singer.get(pos));

        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_album_name, "");
        status = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                        Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                        notificationIntent, 0))
                .build();

        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
//        status = new Notification.Builder(this)
//                .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setOngoing(false)
//                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, new Intent(), 0))
//                .build();
        status.contentView = views;
        status.bigContentView = bigViews;
//        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
//        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_LOCAL_ONLY;
//        status.flags = Notification.F;
        status.icon = R.drawable.status;
        status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(pos));
        NotificationTarget notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(getApplicationContext(),
                bigViews,
                R.id.status_bar_album_art,
                status,
                101
        );
        NotificationTarget notificationTarget_sm = new NotificationTarget(getApplicationContext(),
                views,
                R.id.status_bar_album_art,
                status,
                101);

        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(URLDecoder.decode(uri.toString())));
            if (mmr.getEmbeddedPicture() != null) {
                Glide
                        .with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.logo2)
                        .into(notificationTarget_sm);
                Glide
                        .with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .error(R.drawable.logo2)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.logo2)
                        .into(notificationTarget);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);

//        status.notify();
//        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
    }
```

I don't know much about Notification. Is anybody have idea what happened.

Comment: are you sure you are not using `startForeground` try clean and build

Comment: Which device you are running it?

Comment: @nhoxbypass I'm using  Android N

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh, Yup I'm not using startForeground

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh, Okk I was using startForeground for another notification with the same variable now it's working. I removed startForeground. 
Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As indicated in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159560/notification-is-not-swipable-to-dismiss/47159925#comment81268802_47159560), You need to remove the [`startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) because this will never let user to remove the notification instead use `NotificationManager#notify`

Comment: @Pavneey_Singh, I got a problem in this solution. when the song is playing and I destroyed only activity then song pause and notification buttons works after some time. Do you have any idea what happened??

Comment: @SunnyBhadana the best solution is to debug the code and use some break points , but best guess would be due to recreation(inflating or something) of some component which is causing the delay

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you **cannot** hide notification while your **foreground service is running** (service start with `startForGround()`). It is Google's rule for the users to see that the application is able to run in background.

Try remove `startForGround()`. Or if you still want to keep `startForGround()` and want to give it a try, try replace setting flags with following code:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Detail answer already posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373655/5282585