# React Native notification with Expo is not sticky

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, notifications, expo

I'm using [Expo sdk's notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications.html) in my React Native app (created with create-react-native-app so there is no Java code)

My function for setting the notification is this:

```
putNotif(){
        Notifications.dismissAllNotificationsAsync();

        const localNotification = {
            title: this.state.notifTitle,
            body: this.state.notifMessage,
            android:{
                sticky: true,
                priority:'max'
            }
        }
        Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification);
    }
```

What I want is a sticky notification that is not dismissable by the user, but the notification generated in this way is not sticky despite having `sticky:true`, as it can be user dismissed and also disappears on tap (Opens the app and dismisses the notification)

How do I get the notification to persist?

Also a second question, what should I set the `icon` attribute so as to get the standard alarm clock notification icon in Android?

Comment: Any way to set a flag for the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT as from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718388/android-4-cant-dismiss-notification-by-swiping)?

Comment: @Halcyon I went through the documentation, no way to set the flag unfortunately...

Comment: Still no solution for this?!